# How to avoid override of multiple if-else block?

Tags: javascript

When i click e checkbox then another field will appear and some field will disappear. I wrote a function with simple if-else logic for doing this. but for multiple if-else logic some block override another block. i use return but not still not working. here is my code.

```
   function checkCheckbox() {
        if ($('#irregular').is(":checked")) {
            $('#daysOfInactivity').show();
            $("#targetPointDiv").hide();
            $("#targetTransactionDiv").hide();
            $("#fixedTimeDiv").hide();
            $("#isNumOfTrans").hide();
            return;
        } else {
            $('#daysOfInactivity').hide();
            $("#targetPointDiv").show();
            $("#targetTransactionDiv").show();
            $("#fixedTimeDiv").show();
            $("#isNumOfTrans").show();
            return;
        }
        if ($('#isNumOfTrans').is(":checked")) {
            $('#numOfTrans').show();
            $("#targetPointDiv").hide();
            $("#targetTransactionDiv").hide();
            $("#fixedTimeDiv").hide();
            return;
        } else {
            $('#numOfTrans').hide();
            $("#targetPointDiv").hide();
            $("#targetTransactionDiv").hide();
            $("#fixedTimeDiv").hide();
            return;
        }
```

}

Comment: return should fix it, what exactly is happening, can you give an example?

Comment: The second `if` will never execute, because of the `return;` statements in the first `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: First if-else override by second if-else block when i didn't use return statement. i try it with return but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ [Sayed Mahmud Raihan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7435155/sayed-mahmud-raihan) You can try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#irregular').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('#daysOfInactivity').show();
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv, #isNumOfTrans').hide();

        } else {
           $('#daysOfInactivity').hide();
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv, #isNumOfTrans').show();
        }
    });

    $('#isNumOfTrans').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('#numOfTrans').show();
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv').hide();
        } else 
           $('#numOfTrans, #targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv').hide();

    });
}
```

Or in this way-

```
function checkCheckBox(){
   $('#irregular').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('#daysOfInactivity').show();
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv, #isNumOfTrans').hide();

        } else {
           $('#daysOfInactivity').hide();
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv, #isNumOfTrans').show();
        }
    });

    $('#isNumOfTrans').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('#numOfTrans').show();
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv').hide();
        } else 
           $('#numOfTrans, #targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv').hide();

    });
}
$(document).ready(checkCheckBox);
```

Or this way-

```
function checkCheckBox(){
   $('#irregular').change(function(){
           $('#daysOfInactivity')[$(this).is(":checked")?'show':'hide'];
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv, #isNumOfTrans')[!($(this).is(":checked"))?'show':'hide'];
    });

    $('#isNumOfTrans').change(function(){
           $('#numOfTrans')[(this).is(":checked")?'show':'hide'];
           $('#targetPointDiv, #targetTransactionDiv, #fixedTimeDiv').hide();  
    });
}
$(document).ready(checkCheckBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code segment is never executed:

```
if ($('#isNumOfTrans').is(":checked")) {
        $('#numOfTrans').show();
        $("#targetPointDiv").hide();
        $("#targetTransactionDiv").hide();
        $("#fixedTimeDiv").hide();
        return;
    } else {
        $('#numOfTrans').hide();
        $("#targetPointDiv").hide();
        $("#targetTransactionDiv").hide();
        $("#fixedTimeDiv").hide();
        return;
    }
```

This is because the first if block has a return statement and will never allow the code to reach the above block. This is most likely causing the anomalous behavior! Consider separating the logic from the if blocks, as there are overlapping conditions!

Comment: is there any other easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
   function checkCheckbox(){
 $('#numOfTrans').hide();
 $('#daysOfInactivity').hide();
$("#targetPointDiv").hide();
$("#targetTransactionDiv").hide();
$("#fixedTimeDiv").hide();
$("#isNumOfTrans").hide();

if ($('#irregular').is(":checked")) {
    $('#daysOfInactivity').show();
} else {

    $("#targetPointDiv").show();
    $("#targetTransactionDiv").show();
    $("#fixedTimeDiv").show();
    $("#isNumOfTrans").show();
}
if ($('#isNumOfTrans').is(":checked")) {
    $('#numOfTrans').show();
} 
}
```

I assume this will help you out to remove the return and toggle visibility of the elements.
I strongly recommend @APL approach.